# Rails activerecord query works in sqlite not in MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, mariadb

I have a query problem with sqlite and MariaDB. In development I use sqlite but in server we use MariaDB. In development following query works

```
Author.includes(:books, employes: :universities).where("universities.id is ? and books.year is ?",
                   @author.employes.first.universities.first.id, @book.jahr).references(:employes, :books)
```

but in production this gives error. When I change is to =, it works in server but does not produce any result in local.

```
Author.includes(:books, employes: :universities).where("universities.id = ? and books.year = ?",
                   @author.employes.first.universities.first.id, @book.jahr).references(:employes, :books)
```

This works in server but no result is produced in local.

**Edit**
What if I have something like this?

```
Author.includes(:books, employes: :universities).where("universities.id = ? and books.year = ? and employes.name like ? and id IN ?",
                       @author.employes.first.universities.first.id, @book.jahr, "%#{@employe.name}%", [1,2,3]).references(:employes, :books)
```

Comment: First: Basic architecture design failure using different database servers on development and production ... Second check the generated SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as Raymond said, never use different databases in development and production environment.

But for now you can avoid the SQL syntax errors by going ActiveRecord way, try this

```
Author.includes(:books, employes: :universities).where(
  universities: { id: @author.employes.first.universities.first.id },
  books: { year: @book.jahr }
).references(:employes, :books)
```

Since there's no ActiveRecord alternative for `like`, you can try this (it will work since `like` is valid in both MySQL and SQLite)

```
Author.includes(:books, employes: :universities).where(
  authors: { id: [1,2,3] },
  universities: { id: @author.employes.first.universities.first.id },
  books: { year: @book.jahr }
).where('employes.name like ?', "%#{@employe.name}%").references(:employes, :books)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If pass `where` a Hash, it doesn't need to use `references`

Comment: Hi! it worked great. Could you show me what would be the ActiveRecord way of doing the query in the Edit in question above?